# How can I get a user with a given facebook id using cloud code?

Tags: parse-platform

My app requires facebook login, so it is supposed I have all facebook ids from my users. What I want to o in cloud code is a function that given a facebook id (a string), returns the user (or null if no exists). The problem I see is that it seems the facebook id is inside a json structure in the authData column, but I have no idea how to create a query to access to that information. I found this: https://www.parse.com/questions/how-to-get-the-facebook-id-of-an-pfuser-from-a-pfquery-in-ios but no idea about how to use it.
Can you help me with the function I want to create? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with using `authData` is that you need a valid active session of that user (or use your master key) to access the data.

If you don't already have a large amount of users, I would recommend creating a new column in your User class that stores the Facebook ID so you can query for it later. That way, you could do something like:

```
var query = new Parse.Query("User");
query.equalTo("facebookId", request.params.facebookId);
query.find({
    success: function(results) {
        // do something with the resulting user at results[0], if found
    },
    error: function() {
        response.error("lookup failed");
    }
});
```

Comment: Hello Eric, thanks for reply. Actually, my app is not in production, so I can do whatever I want. Can I add without any problems a field called facebookId and another called firstName? In that case, when exactly should I send that info to the server? just after I see the user.isNew)? In that case, how can I delete the created user if the facebook request was wrong? (something like a transaction). Thanks for comments.

Comment: You should add a column like `facebookId` and put the ID in there when you create the user, if you have it. Whenever you can connect the two together. Other than that I don't really understand what you are asking.

Comment: What I mean is how can I avoid the case of having nothing in that column. Because the second request failed or a network error. Actually, I see I need 3 requests: login request with parse, fql request to get the facebook id, and the last one to upload that facebook id, isn't? Thanks for replies.

Comment: BTW, can I use beforeSave to try to extract facebook id and if fail, return error?

Comment: I don't know how you're obtaining the Facebook IDs. Your questions require a deep understanding of your project's structure to answer and I do not know what your situation really looks like. I think if you have a different problem you should ask a new question.

Comment: This seems insecure. You're giving the user permission to write their own FacebookID. They could use someone else's "facebookId" instead of their own.

Comment: I was assuming he was getting the facebook ID after a successful login. His question does not reveal much about the structure of the app..

Comment: @Gazzini this is in fact an issue if you do not validate the user in CloudCode later on. I would suggest you pass in the userToken with every request and use graphAPI to match the ID in the request and the ID from the graph API response

Comment: @Gazzini I'm sure there are security concerns, but his question was how to query for a user with a given Facebook ID. I tried to answer his question without diving into implementation-specific details.

Comment: @MaxBumaye That would probably be more "correct," but it would also slow things down significantly. However, unless someone finds a way to modify their AuthData on Parse, that really shouldn't be necessary... I don't think?

Answer (score 1):

My comment on Eric's answer expresses my concerns around security, but the cloud-code BeforeSave() function to address my concerns really isn't difficult... for simple use-cases:

```
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave("MyObject", function(request, response) {
    request.object.set("owner_facebook_id", request.user.get("authData").facebook.id);

    response.success();
});
```

In your case, MyObject is the user class, and as long as no users can modify properties on another user object, than this will work pretty well.

However, for the app I was working on, we allowed any user to "like" an object, which incremented a "number_of_likes" property on the object. At that point, this became more tricky, because the user making that request was not, in fact, the owner of the object, so their Facebook_id properties wouldn't have matched.

The work-around was to try and detect whether or not the object had previously existed, and then just make sure the Facebook_id never changed after it was originally created.

We had to access the ORIGINAL object and make sure the newly-saving object had the same Facebook id... it was not exactly trivial, and that lookup actually counts against your request limit. This, combined with a few more edge-cases, caused us to ultimately abandon Parse for that project.